# Porting app from android Playstore to Amazon Appstore - ads display

Tags: android, porting, amazon-appstore

I'm trying to port an android app from Google playstore to Amazon App. My main strategy to monetize is through displaying ads (rewards videos).

I would like to know if the ads displayed in the app when downloaded from Playstore, will show up in the app downloaded from the amazon appstore??

Edit:
Presently using a unity plugin as a mediation for using:
Adcolony, Admob & UnityAds

Comment: what ad framework are you using is the first most obvious REQUIRED information you've left out...

Comment: @KaranHarshWardhan Im sorry for the late reply. I'm using Adcolony, Admob and Unity Ads in the game which is published in Playstore

Comment: I think you can consider Chartboost, maybe it is good choice too. Sorry to too late reply too!!!